# SignalR Private Chat Not Returning Data

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I implemented SignalR to my project. But I have problem sending private message. I am sending 'toConnectionID' from page.

ChatHub.cs

```
public void LoadPrivateMessages(string toUserName,string toConnectionID)
        {
            var chatHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();             
            string fromUserName = Context.QueryString["userName"].ToString();
            string fromConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId;

            List<ChatMessageDetail> currentMessages = cachePrivateMessages.Where(x => x.ToUserName == toUserName && x.FromUserName == fromUserName && x.ToConnectionID==toConnectionID && x.FromConnectionID==fromConnectionID).ToList();


            chatHub.Clients.Client(toConnectionID).privateMessagesHistory(currentMessages);

        }
```

My currentMessages list is filling. I am OK here. But I can't take messages to page.

Javascript

```
chatHub.client.privateMessagesHistory = function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            };
```

My console screen is null after this JavaScript code.

Edit :

That is my connection code in document.ready function. Second is sending information about receiver.

```
var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
            $.connection.hub.qs = { "userName": "@Session["userName"]" };
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log("Connection OK !");
        });


 $(document).on('click','.onlineUser', function () {
            var userName = $(this).attr('id');//That is which user to send(Receiver)
            var toConnectionID = $(this).attr('connectionID');
            chatHub.server.loadPrivateMessages(userName, toConnectionID);
            $('.privateMessagediv').show();
            $('.userName').html("");
            $('.userName').append("<h4>" + userName + "</h4>");
            $('.btnSendingPrivateMessage').attr('id', userName);
            $('.btnSendingPrivateMessage').attr('connectionid', toConnectionID);

            chatHub.client.privateMessagesHistory = function (data) {
                $('#privateChatBox').append(data);

            };
        });
```

Edit 2 :

I solved issue.

```
chatHub.Clients.Client(fromConnectionID).privateMessagesHistory(currentMessages);
```

instead of

```
chatHub.Clients.Client(toConnectionID).privateMessagesHistory(currentMessages);
```

Comment: can you show your client-side registration? There are another 2 steps I'd like to check

Comment: @reckface Sure.

Comment: @reckface I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original suspicion was with the `toConnectionId`, but after examining your `privateMessageHistory` callback registration, it's more likely a timing issue.

You need to **setup the client callback before the hub** `.start()`.

From [Microsoft:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#establishconnection)

> Normally you register event handlers before calling the start method
>   to establish the connection. If you want to register some event
>   handlers after establishing the connection, you can do that, but you
>   must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the
>   start method

There's no need to place your callback registration in the click event.

```
var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
$.connection.hub.qs = { "userName": "@Session["userName"]" };
// callback first
chatHub.client.privateMessagesHistory = function (data) {
    $('#privateChatBox').append(data);
};
// start the hub connection - note chatHub is different from your .hub
chatHub.start().done(function () {
    console.log("Connection OK !");
});
```

Comment: Thanks your question. But my scenario is firstly, user click the name of user after private chatbox will open and then loading old messages between them. I can't understand why I setup client call back before ? :( How is my code should be ?

Comment: I tried your solution but I got error. $.connection.chatHub.start is not a function

Comment: I changed $.connection.hub.start(). No data return.

Comment: @Developer007 in your snippet you said `var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;`. Either your snippet is wrong or you've made an error.

Comment: @rekface Hello again me. I came across a strange situation. When I clicked my nick name, data is coming. But when I click other user nick name not coming :)

Comment: because the connection Id is unique to individual users, and you're sending the message to a single connection. btw, if this answered your question, then mark it acordingly